# Add class to specific image in a slider caroufredsel

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I've a slider which having 6 images and that shows only 3 images at a time using caroufredsel jquery.  I need to add border to the middle slider image (using class). How can I do this?

My code is,

```
        $('#gallery').carouFredSel({
            width: '100%',
            auto: true,
            items: {
                visible: 3,
                start: -1,

            },
            swipe: {
                onMouse: true,
                onTouch: true
            },
            scroll: {
                items: 1,
                duration: 1000,
                timeoutDuration: 3000

            },

            prev: '#WorkPrev',
            next: '#WorkNext'
        });
```

html is,

```
  <div class="galleryWrap">
        <div id="gallery">
            <div class="galleryImage"> <img src="img/slider2img1.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="galleryImage"> <img src="img/slider2img2.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="galleryImage"> <img src="img/slider2img3.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="galleryImage"> <img src="img/slider2img4.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="galleryImage"> <img src="img/slider2img5.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="galleryImage"> <img src="img/slider2img6.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Help me. Thanks for advance

Comment: Add html code or jsfiddle example if possible

Comment: you have 9 images or 6? whatever add a class to middle three images and add border to it in css if thats what you want. or wrap middle three images in a div with a class and add border to that class.

Comment: 6 images I have. The slider shows 3 images at a time from the 6 images and rotates (one image hides and one image shows in the 3 images) in a specific time. I need to highlight the middle image (from the showing 3 images) using css

Comment: You can do it through their callback, have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the carouFredSel callback functions

adding border directly

```
$('#gallery').carouFredSel({
        // your all other properties come here
        auto: {
            onBefore : function( data ) {
                var vis_elements;
                vis_elements  = $("#gallery").triggerHandler("configuration", "items.visible");
                var mid_element =  Math.floor(vis_elements/2);
                $.each(data.items.visible, function () { $(this).css({'border': ''})});
                data.items.visible.eq(mid_element).css({'border': '1px solid'});
           }
        }
    });
```

or you can also add css class to the element

```
auto: {
                onBefore : function( data ) {
                    var vis_elements;
                    vis_elements  = $("#gallery").triggerHandler("configuration", "items.visible");
                    var mid_element =  Math.floor(vis_elements/2);

                    $.each(data.items.visible, function () { 
                      // remove class from all other elements
                      $(this).removeClass("your class"); // your class comes here
                    });

                    // add your class here
                    data.items.visible.eq(mid_element).addClass("your class");
               }
            }
```

Check the http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/rgqfz/

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to stackoverflow. So my reputation is below than 15.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :) but i think you can accept not upvote not sure though..

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Dnv23/3/

**CSS:-**

```
.galleryImage{float:left}

.galleryImage:nth-child(3n+2){  
  border: 4px solid #ccc;
}
```

**JS:-**

```
$('#gallery').carouFredSel({
    auto: true,
    items: 3,
    swipe: {
        onMouse: true,
        onTouch: true
    },
    scroll: {
        items: 3,
        duration: 1000,
        timeoutDuration: 3000

    },

    prev: '#WorkPrev',
    next: '#WorkNext'
});
```